# Sorting on anything but the first column with QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: qt, pyqt, qsortfilterproxymodel

I'm using PyQt5, and I've got a `QTreeView` using a `QSortFilterProxyModel` to get its data. Sorting is enabled on the table, and in fact if I click on the header for the first column it sorts properly on that column. However, if I click on any other header, it appears that the proxy model somehow decides not to sort.

Instead, I see (in the debugger) that `sort()` is called on my proxy-model, and it's called with the correct column and order. However, none of the sorting machinery seems to be invoked after that: `lessThan()` is not called, `data()` is not invoked on my items, etc. In fact, it appears that the table goes back to its original, unsorted order (i.e. its state prior to ordering it by the first column).

As far as I can tell, my model is defined properly, and in fact it works perfectly in the rest of the application. I feel like I must be missing something silly here, but I'm blind to whatever it is. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the type of data for columns that do not sort?

Comment: Most are string, but some are int.

Comment: @abingham provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc https://github.com/abingham/pyqt-column-sorting-example